# Python generate 16 random numner and letter in a new column dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I would like to create a string that contains random number and letter total 16, in a column in a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[ 'Apr 2'], ['Jan 1'], [ 'Jan 18']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date'])
```

Expected result

[image]

my approch doesn't work, because it give me the same randon number/letter for every rows

```
import uuid; df['id'] = uuid.uuid4().hex.upper()[0:16]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current assignment to `df['id']` will broadcast the value to the whole column. Try this ...

```py
df['id'] = [uuid.uuid4().hex.upper()[0:16] for _ in range(len(df.index))]
```